# YouTube Data API v3: invalid search filters and/or restrictions for certain Freebase topics

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, freebase

I am trying to do a YouTube topic search using the YouTube Data API v3. I've found that there are many seemingly popular Freebase topics for which YouTube returns no results even though the safeSearch parameter is set to "none". For instance, when I try to search YouTube for the topic "alcoholic beverage" (/m/012mj) the API throws an exception.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError

DEVELOPER_KEY = "blah blah"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
  developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
topic_id = "/m/012mj"
try:
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    topicId=topic_id,
    type="video",
    part="id",
    safeSearch="none",
    q="",
  ).execute()
except HttpError,e:
  print e

<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?topicId=%2Fm%2F012mj&q=&safeSearch=none&part=id&key=AIzaSyC7MDamoleicn233r8mTyK2sohcV4A3Aq8&alt=&type=video returned "Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.">
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

This no longer returns a 400 error. The API now returns a search response with no items. At least this helps me differentiate between an error and a search response with no results. However, it still seems strange that YouTube won't return search results for this topic even with safeSearch set to "none".

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered setting the max-results parameter?  I have no experience with the YouTube flavor of the Freebase api, but have [read](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters) that they recommend limiting the results for videos to 10 rather than accepting the default of 25.  Otherwise it is odd that they would send a 400 (bad request) rather than a 401 or so.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried this out, but had no luck.

Comment: I am having same issue, i am trying to use videoEmbeddable...did you find any work around?